# Finding documentation for arcpy.gp functions?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, documentation

I'm learning ArcPy and trying to export models to Python scripts to get a feel for it. I have a model that generalizes a land cover raster by reclassifying and using some other spatial analyst tools (boundary clean, region group, extract by attributes, and nibble). When I export my model each function is under arcpy.gp, e.g.:

```
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa(...)
arcpy.gp.BoundaryClean_sa(...)
arcpy.gp.RegionGroup_sa(...)
```

And so on. I gather this means "Use the geoprocessing tool Reclassify from the Spatial Analyst extension" but I can't find any documentation for it. I can find `arcpy.sa.Reclassify` but not the `arcpy.gp` version. Does anyone know where to look?

Comment: If you are learning ArcPy be aware of the Copy As Python Snippet function in the Geoprocessing   | Results window. It makes much easier to follow code than exporting models.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good heads up. Still leaves me wondering where to find documentation for the arcpy.gp functions, though. If that's a default from the export process, you'd think documentation would be easier to find.

Comment: You'll want to use `sa` in your script. Read this: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/146373

Comment: That's helpful. So I guess Esri doesn't provide any documentation for the arcpy.gp functions then, just adds a parameter for output. That's ... frustrating.

Comment: The documentation is for the `sa`. You don't need documentation for `gp` since it'd be the exact same.

Comment: Not necessarily the case. Consider Reclassify. `sa.Reclassify` takes a RemapValue or RemapRange object, but `gp.Reclassify_sa` takes a string.

Comment: The model to python conversion is rubbish. Use arcpy.sa methods, not arcpy.gp and the documentation is http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/complete-listing-of-spatial-analyst-tools.htm

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll do moving forward. But for folks like me who are new to ArcPy, it's important to know that 1) model conversion will call arcpy.gp functions and 2) those aren't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where I think you should expect to find the `gp` module to be documented is via the left hand panel of [A quick tour of ArcPy](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy/a-quick-tour-of-arcpy.htm).

However, as you can see it appears not to be documented.

[image]

You could submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) to have this addressed for the ArcGIS Desktop architecture but, if it is still an issue for the ArcGIS Pro architecture then it may be better to make that your target.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and the pointer to ArcGIS Idea. I don't have access to ArcGIS Pro at this time so I'll submit something for ArcGIS Desktop.