# Calling help for ArcPy function from within IDE

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-2.7, slope, idle

In IDLE (for Python v2.7.2 within my ESRI path), when I type:

```
help(arcpy.gp.Slope_sa)
```

I get:

```
Help on function <lambda> in module arcpy.geoprocessing._base:

<lambda> lambda *args
```

which is not particularly helpful.

How do I access proper help?

Comment: Have you looked at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm

Comment: Aye.  That's what I normally use, but am having an odd problem that makes me think the command is looking for args in a different sequence than their online documentation.  Figured I'd try native, standalone Python help as a check.  Cheers

Comment: I rarely touch the Spatial Analyst extension but I find the `arcpy.gp.<tool>_sa` and `arcpy.sa.<tool>` distinction confusing.  This GeoNet post may or may not clarify it a bit: https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/what-is-the-difference-between-arcpy-gp-visibility-sa-and-arcpy/td-p/42338  Likewise this earlier Q&A here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/228287/115

Comment: @PolyGeo - Thank-you for bringing the different behaviours to my attention. The solution was to use arcpy.sa instead of arcpy.gp.  I had casually wondered 'why', but assumed (and experienced) interchangeability. Cheers!